# unrecognized option cron for time maven

Tags: java, stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to create a Stream on Spring Cloud Data Flow, it is working fine for me but when i try to add Cron to the stream it gives me error and I'm unable to create required stream. 
Here is my Stream: `time-maven --cron='0 0 20 * * ?'| GeneralDataFeeds | log-maven`
and the error: unrecognized option 'cron' for 'time-maven'

can anyone help me with this? I'm unable to find anything from Google.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an issue in Flo designer with respect to the supported properties and validation, but it has been addressed in the 1.6.x release.

Please upgrade to the latest [1.6.x GA or 1.7 M1](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#platform-implementations) release to get around the incorrect validation issues.